# EF core migration - Class does not contain a definition of property

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, asp.net-core-1.1

I have asp.net core application build on 1.0.0-rtm-21431 version which i updated to 1.1.2 and successfully deploy on azure.

Today, I add new columns to model. Made "add-migration nameofmigration" and "update-database -verbose"  . On localhost everything works fine, but on azure i get errors on model

```
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public string Key { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Názov")]
        public string Heading { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Kalórie")]
        public int Cal { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Bielkoviny")]
        public int Protein { get; set; }

    }
```

migration code:

```
public partial class kcal : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "Cal",
                table: "Recipes",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);

            migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
                name: "Protein",
                table: "Recipes",
                nullable: false,
                defaultValue: 0);

        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Cal",
                table: "Recipes");

            migrationBuilder.DropColumn(
                name: "Protein",
                table: "Recipes");

        }
    }
```

===========================================================================

```
'Recipe' does not contain a definition for 'Cal' and no extension method 'Cal' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
        #pragma warning restore 1998
'Recipe' does not contain a definition for 'Cal' and no extension method 'Cal' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
        #pragma warning restore 1998
'Recipe' does not contain a definition for 'Cal' and no extension method 'Cal' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
        #pragma warning restore 1998
'Recipe' does not contain a definition for 'Protein' and no extension method 'Protein' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
+
        #pragma warning restore 1998
'Recipe' does not contain a definition for 'Protein' and no extension method 'Protein' accepting a first argument of type 'Recipe' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

localhost and deploy site use SAME azure database

Did I miss some code changes between core 1.0.0 rtm and 1.1.2 ?

Comment: Can you share the generated migration?

Comment: I updated code above.

Comment: When do you receive the error? During migrating the database?  Are you doing that from Visual Studio?  Those messages seem to be a compilation error.

Comment: Migration was done successfully from Package Manager Console (vs 2017 community). Error is displayed on pages where new properties are used (Create / Edit) . These pages works fine locally on localhost, but errors are displayed ONLY on deloyed site (azurewebsites.net)

Comment: Can you try a solution Rebuild?  I think that your View code might be out of sync with your data code.

Comment: After 3 days I found solution: I stopped site at porta.azure.com , via FTP removed all files, rebuild solution and redeploy again

Comment: I think you may run into this again in the future, you may want to set up precompiled views: https://scottsauber.com/2017/03/10/pre-compiling-razor-views-in-asp-net-core-with-csprojs/